# Diet soft drinks and Diabetes

Tags: diabetes, type-2-diabetes, pre-diabetes, sweeteners

I have heard many times, for example [in HealthLine](https://www.healthline.com/health/diabetes-diet-soda) and [in Patient Info](https://patient.info/news-and-features/can-diet-drinks-cause-type-2-diabetes) that diet soft drinks can be just as bad as sugary soft drinks when it comes to risk of diabetes.

I am also reading what **seems to be** conflicting information such as [this article from DiabetesUK](https://www.diabetes.org.uk/guide-to-diabetes/enjoy-food/what-to-drink-with-diabetes) which suggest drinking diet or light versions of hot chocolate.

What is the status of diet drinks and diabetes risk?